# Who generates the coinbase transaction?

Tags: mining-reward

As the wiki article says,

> Given just those fields, people would frequently generate the exact
>   same sequence of hashes as each other and the fastest CPU would almost
>   always win. However, it is (nearly) impossible for two people to have
>   the same Merkle root because the first transaction in your block is a
>   generation "sent" to one of your unique Bitcoin addresses.][1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm)

Who generates the coinbase transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coinbase transaction is not relayed by the network. It is invalid except as the first transaction in a block.

A standalone miner generates the coinbase transaction itself.

In mining pools, the mining pool generates the coinbase, and sends it to the mining client.